# Проблема с рекламой

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть игра, в которой будет показана реклама(UnityAds). Однако я столкнулся с проблемой:

> Assets\scripts\ad.cs(13,39): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ad' to 'UnityEngine.Advertisements.IUnityAdsListener'

Не понимаю, что он от  меня хочет и как это решить.
Код:

```
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;


public class ad : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        if (Application.internetReachability != NetworkReachability.NotReachable)
        {
            Advertisement.AddListener(this);
            Advertisement.Initialize("4661845", true);
        }
    }
    public void ShowAd()
    {
        if(Advertisement.isInitialized)
        {
            Advertisement.Show("Rewarded_Android");
        }
    }
    public void OnUnityAdsDidFinish(string placementId, ShowResult showResult)
    {
        if(showResult == ShowResult.Finished)
        {
            Debug.Log("Реклама");
        }
    }
}
```

Делал по [Ролику](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dvK4tK9cBIQ)

Comment: Мне кажется надо применение класса посмотреть. а может не хватает `, IUnityAdsListener` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Да, проблема была в этом. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К строке `public class ad : MonoBehaviour` нужно добавить `, IUnityAdsListener`:

public class ad : MonoBehaviour, IUnityAdsListener